# SparkJava: index.hbs FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, spark-java

I developed a web app with SparkJava framework. The app works fine when I run it from Eclipse. When I pack it to a jar file, run the jar file and open web app in browser I receive a 500 Internal Error.

Console returns a FileNotFoundException. The hbs file is located in src/main/resources/templates.

```
org.eclipse.jetty.io.RuntimeIOException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /templates/index.hbs
    at spark.template.handlebars.HandlebarsTemplateEngine.render(HandlebarsTemplateEngine.java:78) ~[jar:rsrc:spark-template-handlebars-2.7.1.jar!/:?]
    at App.lambda$0(App.java:42) ~[rsrc:./:?]
    at spark.SparkBase$1.handle(SparkBase.java:264) ~[jar:rsrc:spark-core-2.1.jar!/:?]
    at spark.webserver.MatcherFilter.doFilter(MatcherFilter.java:154) [jar:rsrc:spark-core-2.1.jar!/:?]
    at spark.webserver.JettyHandler.doHandle(JettyHandler.java:60) [jar:rsrc:spark-core-2.1.jar!/:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:179) [jar:rsrc:jetty-server-9.0.2.v20130417.jar!/:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:136) [jar:rsrc:jetty-server-9.0.2.v20130417.jar!/:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerList.handle(HandlerList.java:52) [jar:rsrc:jetty-server-9.0.2.v20130417.jar!/:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97) [jar:rsrc:jetty-server-9.0.2.v20130417.jar!/:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:451) [jar:rsrc:jetty-server-9.0.2.v20130417.jar!/:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.run(HttpChannel.java:252) [jar:rsrc:jetty-server-9.0.2.v20130417.jar!/:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:266) [jar:rsrc:jetty-server-9.0.2.v20130417.jar!/:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.run(AbstractConnection.java:240) [jar:rsrc:jetty-io-9.0.2.v20130417.jar!/:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:596) [jar:rsrc:jetty-util-9.0.2.v20130417.jar!/:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:527) [jar:rsrc:jetty-util-9.0.2.v20130417.jar!/:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_181]
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /templates/index.hbs
    at com.github.jknack.handlebars.io.URLTemplateLoader.sourceAt(URLTemplateLoader.java:70) ~[jar:rsrc:handlebars-4.0.6.jar!/:?]
    at com.github.jknack.handlebars.Handlebars.compile(Handlebars.java:357) ~[jar:rsrc:handlebars-4.0.6.jar!/:?]
    at com.github.jknack.handlebars.Handlebars.compile(Handlebars.java:343) ~[jar:rsrc:handlebars-4.0.6.jar!/:?]
    at spark.template.handlebars.HandlebarsTemplateEngine.render(HandlebarsTemplateEngine.java:75) ~[jar:rsrc:spark-template-handlebars-2.7.1.jar!/:?]
```

What I do not understand, why does it work when I run it in Eclipse but not when I pack it to a jar.

Any idea what the problem could be?

Comment: does the archive file(war or jar) contains the /templates/index.hbs? open it using mc on Linux or Winrar on windows and check if it exists.

Comment: @epcpu I checked that already. It is included in the jar file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue on my own. The problem was with Eclipse. Since it can be useful for others who have the same problem, I'll create the answer myself.

The problem was caused by the fact that /src/main/resource folder was included in the Java Build Path, but for some reason not all subfolders were included. The value "**" was assigned to the "*Excluded:*" item. After I changed the value to "(None)", the template files were found.

[image: Solution is to assign value (None) to *Excluded* item]

Answer (score 1):

URLTemplateLoader.sourceAt() throws this because getResource() return null,here is the code:

```
  protected URL getResource(final String location) throws IOException {
    File file = new File(location);
    return file.exists() ? file.toURI().toURL() : null;
  }
```

You passing a relative path to File constructor and it's resolved from working dir.

> A pathname, whether abstract or in string form, may be either absolute or relative. An absolute pathname is complete in that no other information is required in order to locate the file that it denotes. A relative pathname, in contrast, must be interpreted in terms of information taken from some other pathname. By default the classes in the java.io package always resolve relative pathnames against the current user directory. This directory is named by the system property user.dir, and is typically the directory in which the Java virtual machine was invoked.

[File javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html)

Comment: Thanks, I understood the problem, but I do not know how to solve it in this case?

Comment: read a javadoc, and use ClassPathTemplateLoader then creating  Handlebars https://github.com/jknack/handlebars.java/blob/master/handlebars/src/main/java/com/github/jknack/handlebars/Handlebars.java

Comment: I tried different ways with the absolute and relative path and the classloader, but unfortunately I couldn't solve the problem.